# Pass Initialized model through View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Simple question, but I cannot find solution anywhere.
I have 1 Get ActionResult, 1 Post ActionResult and 1 View.
In the Get method I initialize some part from the model.
After that in the View I initialize the other part.
When the model comes in Post method, it is not initialized well.
How to pass the data throught View and Methods?
I don't want to use Temporary objects.

Example:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register(Guid product_id)
    {

        RegistrationModel model = new RegistrationModel();

        model.Product = **someProduct**;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Register(RegistrationModel model, Product Product)
    {
                 Here the objects comes initialized only with the parts from the view...
    }
```

Comment: Once the model is sent to the view, are you carrying that data to the browser? If not, they don't exist across round trips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how the MVC works. 
There is a concept called **Model Binding** which is responsible for Mapping a `Model` with ***suitable*** HTML.

When I say ***suitable*** I mean that it needs to be formatted according to specific rules. 
In Order to simplify the things, MVC has inbuilt `HtmlHelpers` which handles the transition between a `Model`'s property to an HTML Element.

From your `[HttpGet]` method you may return:

1) a model-less view `return View();`

2) a view with a Blank model `return View(new Product());`

3) a view with a model which contains some data `return View(product);`

Inside the View, you should decide:

1) If you only want to **display** the model you could use **(may not be wrapped in a `form`)**:

- `HtmlHelpers` like `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)`
- Simple Model calls like `<h1>@Model.Name</h1>`

2) If you want some data to be **posted back** to your `[HttpPost]` you should

Take care to "Map" a Model's property to an HTML element specifically **(everything wrapped inside a `form` )**:

- Through `HtmlHelpers` like `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price)`, which will generate a "suitable" HTML output:`<input id="Price" name="Price" value="">52.00</input>` (recommended)
- Through well formatted HTML (***suitable*** ^_^ ):

---

```
   <select id="SelectedLanguageId" name="SelectedLanguageId">
       <option value="1">English</option>
       <option value="2">Russian</option>
    </select>
```

### To summarize:

1)If you want to receive something back to a `[HttpPost]` method you should have a `suitable` HTML element inside your .

2)If you want only to **display** some data you could simply call model's property

3)Use HTML helpers instead of raw HTML code.

## Note!

Model binding on complex `Model`s is achieved through **EditorTemplates**, **Hidden inputs inside Loops**, **Different kind of Serialization** etc.

Comment: Actually I know all of that you write, but I was wondering for some way to save data through requests without using ViewData, Session or TempData. I resolved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. From my experience if it is a simple scenario I'm serializing data or storing it with nested loops. Otherwise if the model is too complex, and there are too many dependencies I just use the session `HttpContext.Session["MyComplexViewModel"]= complexModel;`. And always make some CRUD operations based on the session. Such scenario may be a **Wizard-Like** Insert of an order which has steps, validation of data etc.