# Modelbinder not binds nested collection's own properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have complex objects with nested collections. I have no problem binding extrem nested collections in the past. However some of my collection classes now has defined own properties. It seems that the model binder completly ignore these properties.

Example:

```
public class C
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class CList : Collection<C>
{
    public string OwnProperty { get; set; }
}


public class Model
{
    public CList CList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I cannot bind anything to Model.CList.OwnProperty, but binding items in the collection works. 
An input with name

"CList[0].SomeProperty" --> works, add an item to the collection

"CList[1].SomeProperty" --> works, add an item to the collection

"CList.OwnProperty" --> model binder not works, not set the collection property.

Comment: Take a look  at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369213/pass-initialized-model-through-view/22374808#22374808

Comment: This is not relevant at all to my question. I know how model binder works, what should be in the name attributes, what is html helpers and so on. The model binder perfectly binds my nested classes, but not binds any property of a nested class if it is a collection (the collections itself populated)

Comment: In this Post is says that Model binding on complex Models is achieved through EditorTemplates, Hidden inputs inside Loops, Different kind of Serialization etc.So if you want model binder to get working on collection you should wrap it inside loop ,you need to make hidden each object from collection.

Comment: The model binder for complex objects works perfectly without any html helper or editortemplate...